# Create DataSource using JBoss 7 JNDI and Spring

Tags: spring, datasource, jboss7.x, applicationcontext

I am first time making a webapp for Jboss server.
For JBoss we have the jndi details, but I am wondering how to create the Datasource using it in spring application context.

If anyone has an example to create the connection, please share it.

Comment: It's mentioned in title Jboss 7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

Add below configuration to applicationContext.xml

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd"

<jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/SAMPLE_JNDI"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will put this sample here.

just to show another way to do it.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:jboss/datasources/DSName</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```