# How to use jndi datasource in Jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss

In Jboss 5 i used a datasource for a remote DB, something as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
         <jndi-name>dsName</jndi-name>
          ...
         <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:2074:xx</connection-url>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

and i called from my applicationContext.xml in this way:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:dsName"/>
</bean>
```

it is possibile to do in Jboss7?
In these posts
[JBoss 7.1 - declare datasource and access via JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261676/jboss-7-1-declare-datasource-and-access-via-jndi)
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/196876

i have found that ***"Remote lookup of datasources is not supported in AS7."***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> WildFly (and AS7) don't support remote datasource lookup, which I believe is a deliberate decision. If you used it on older versions where it worked, it was incredibly easy to create terrible performance problems, large server-side memory leaks, and more.
>
> What was the use case for having one? The best option is usually to encapsulate the data logic in an EJB which does the DB work server-side, and then call it from the client.

[Source discussion](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241500)

That said I am not sure if you are actually trying to use "remote" datasource lookup. Check out the guides for datasource configuration basics.

[Create DataSource using JBoss 7 JNDI and Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663874/create-datasource-using-jboss-7-jndi-and-spring)

[Data Source Configuration in AS 7](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7)

Comment: i have tried in this way:

<bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="java:/jboss/myds"/>
      <property name="resourceRef">
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
   </bean>    
   
and in this way: 

   <jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="springBeanIdForSampleDS" jndi-name="java:/jboss/myds"/>

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i get

***Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in URL [file:...
applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [remote://localhost:4447 (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)***

it works only if i configure the datasource in this way:

```
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
               <property name="url"  >
                  <value>...</value>
               </property>
               <property name="username"  >
                  <value>...</value>
               </property>
               <property name="password"  >
                  <value>...</value>
               </property>


         </bean>
```

without jndi, directly in applicationContext.xml

thanks